# Fantasy young adult novel with a girl who lived in a city surrounded by walls

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, urban-fantasy

The girl lived in a magic city where the wall protecting them was filled with magic. Only kids had magic, it was drained from adults, and this girl goes to gets drained, but they inject magic into her and then take it back over and over again. Then she has some weird romantic subplot before escaping the city and meeting this scraggly dude who at first she does not trust but then learns to trust. She also befriends one of the robotic fairy scouts and the robotic fairy ends up developing a personality.

She finds a city of people who can constantly make their own magic but then the savage guy ends up going crazy and getting captured, and she gets really upset. Eventually she kills the entire city, she leaves with the fairy, then the book ends. I read it a few years ago and I can't remember what it's called.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is [Skylark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10352973-skylark)
by Megean Spooner

Summary from Goodreads seems to match up

> Her world ends at the edge of the vast domed barrier of energy enclosing all that’s left of humanity. For two hundred years the city has sustained this barrier by harvesting its children's innate magical energy when they reach adolescence. When it’s Lark’s turn to be harvested, she finds herself trapped in a nightmarish web of experiments and learns she is something out of legend itself: a Renewable, able to regenerate her own power after it’s been stripped.
>
> Forced to flee the only home she knows to avoid life as a human battery, Lark must fight her way through the terrible wilderness beyond the edge of the world. With the city’s clockwork creations close on her heels and a strange wild boy stalking her in the countryside, she must move quickly if she is to have any hope of survival. She’s heard the stories that somewhere to the west are others like her, hidden in secret—but can she stay alive long enough to find them?”